# Show total price for modifier in Expresso Store

Tags: expressionengine, modifier, expresso-store

Is there a way to show the total price for products with modifiers in dropdowns instead of how much extra they are?

For instance, in the shop I'm developing, a bouquet of flowers costs £30 for a regular size. You can also get a large for an additional £20, or a deluxe for an additional £40. I would like the dropdowns to say:
Regular £30
Large £50
Deluxe £70

instead of

Regular £30
Large +20
Deluxe +40

But I want them to all appear in the same drop-down for the one product.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I think you're looking for the `{price_inc_mod}` variable, inside the `{modifier_options}` loop.

https://www.exp-resso.com/docs/product_tag.html#price-inc-mod

Keep in mind that this only makes sense if your products have a single modifier. You can also use [dynamic price variables](https://www.exp-resso.com/docs/product_tag.html#dynamic_product_variables) to display the updated product price using javascript.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks! Worked great.